# How to read value of a cell which refrences other sheet cells?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a cell with below formula on `sheet_B`,

`=IF(sheet_A!$E$66="OOO","XYZ","ABC")`

and I am reading it using OleDb, as below

`cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ["B"]";`

using data set, the cell value always returns ABC, irrespective of `sheet_A` column value, ..

it seems, this is because of the reference is not there while reading `sheet B`,

How can I solve this problem?